# How to change the text color for the InputTextLayout in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, android-styles, android-studio-3.0

**Edit:**
The bar I wanted to get rid of was the bar at the top which says testing. The text color I want to change is "testing@gmail.com" text which the user inputs:

[image: UI]

Here is my XML for the login activity (I used the default login activity provided by android studio):

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.uname.myapp.LoginActivity">

    <!-- Login progress -->
    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/login_progress"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:visibility="gone" />

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/login_form"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/email_login_form"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <AutoCompleteTextView
                    android:id="@+id/email"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:hint="@string/prompt_email"
                    android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    android:singleLine="true" />

            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/password"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:hint="@string/prompt_password"
                    android:imeActionId="6"
                    android:imeActionLabel="@string/action_sign_in_short"
                    android:imeOptions="actionUnspecified"
                    android:inputType="textPassword"
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    android:singleLine="true" />

            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/email_sign_in_button"
                style="?android:textAppearanceSmall"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:text="@string/action_sign_in"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

I wanted to remove the bar at the top, so the solution shown online was to inherit from `Theme.AppComtact.NoActionBar`. Here is my style:

```
<style name="MyTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/white</item>
        <item name="android:textColorHint">@android:color/darker_gray</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/black</item>
    </style>
```

Getting frustrated that I can't find documentation on the `TextInputLayout` and how to simply just change the font color when typing in the textfield. Tried searching on SO and other sites and couldn't find a solution.

I even tried `<item name="android:colorControlNormal">@android:color/black</item>` but it requires API level 21 and 15 is min right now.

Coming from a Python / Django background and first time trying to learn android development.

Can anyone point me in the right direction? Is there documentation that shows all the possible styling developers can apply on text?

My `androidmanifest` file has this in the application:

```
android:theme="@style/MyTheme"
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

if you want to remove action bar or titlebar use this style and make necessary true/false depending what you want and not.

```
<style name="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar.FullScreen" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
</style>
```

and in your manifest file

```
<activity
   android:name=".activities.FullViewActivity"
   android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar.FullScreen" 
/>
```

and for changing font colour

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/myEditText"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="Your Name"
    android:textColor="#FF0000"
</EditText>
```

Comment: Can we put changing the InputTextLyout widget color inside a style? I want it to be app wide. For your current solution, which file do I put the `<EditText ...` code in?

Comment: Also, the code for removing the action bar unfortunately does not successfully remove the bar I want to remove. I updated my question to show which bar it is that I wanted to remove. Please have a look. Thank you.

Comment: I made the parent of the style `parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"` and it successfully removed the action bar. Thanks for the help regarding the action bar!

Comment: welcome. you can change your email input from <AutoCompleteTextView> to <EditText>

Comment: Okay thanks. Is it possible to change the text input color for All <EditText> widgets in my app? Because I have multiple <EditText> widgets in the app and I have to change the text color for all of them? Can I somehow place it within the `name="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar.FullScreen"` style?

Comment: yes, go to values folder then colors.xml then insert your color e.g. 

`<color name="colorPrimary">#e91e63</color>`

and then use it later `android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"`
and for particular style e.g. 

     `<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="drawerArrowStyle">@style/DrawerArrowStyle</item>
    </style>`

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for only setting TextInputLayout hint color then you should try this

> app:hintTextAppearance="@style/text_appearance_color"

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:id="@+id/tilSample"
        app:errorTextAppearance="@style/error_appearance"
        app:hintTextAppearance="@style/text_appearance_color"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/etSample"
            android:layout_margin="8dp"
            android:padding="8dp"
            android:hint="android"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

and for NoActionBar, your code seems to be fine just apply the theme in the manifest at the application level.

**Edit:**
style

```
<style name="editTextStyle" parent="@android:style/Widget.EditText">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/someBackground</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">#808080</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">45dip</item>
    <!--other attibutes goes here-->
</style>
```

Comment: I do not want to change the hint color, I use `<item name="android:textColorHint">@android:color/darker_gray</item>` to change the hint color already. When the user starts typing inside the input text box, the color is white (on a white background). I wish to change the color of the text which appears when the user starts to type inside the input textbox.

Comment: android:textColor="#000" is this not working, for changing the text color ?

Comment: `android:textColor="#000"` only works if I place it inside the XML file in the `<EditText>` / `<TextInputLayout>` tag. I want to be able to control the text color from a style, because I have multiple  `<EditText>` / `<TextInputLayout>` widgets across the app, and having to add `android:textColor="#000"` to every widget doesn't seem like a safe solution. Is it possible to change the color more "globally"? Like from the `styles.xml` file / theme?

Comment: @vikarkumar the issue with creating an entirely new style is, my app already uses a theme called `MyTheme`. The theme is described in `styles.xml` using the `style` tag. If I create another style called `editTextStyle` which inherits from `@android:style/Widget.EditText`, how do I tell my app to use the `editTextStyle` theme / style as well (in addition to using `MyTheme`)? It does not allow me to have two `android:theme="@style/` in my app's manifest.